# Can I run jsp files on usual web hosting?

Tags: jsp

I have simple question: Can I run JSP files on usual web hosting or I have to host my site on JAVA hosting?

Comment: Your web host needs to support JSP. Most run-off-the-mill Linux/PHP packages don't. You need to talk to the web host and find out

Answer (score 1):

You need a host that provides at least a servlet container (like Tomcat), to properly run JavaServer Pages.
Otherwise the web server could still offer your JSP pages (with some tweaking of the server configuration I guess) as static content (i.e. HTML pages with .jsp extension).